# How to pass data from directive to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on integrating a plugin in my angular application and I'm trying to convert it into a directive. I have fiddled around with the events and methods of the plugin but failed to get the desired results. here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="input-daterange datepicker full" rangepicker ng-model="packer.selected.date">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    <div class="inputs datepicker">
        <input 
            ng-model="packer.selected.date.start"
           name="start" 
           value="<% packer.initData.dateStart %>">
        <span class="add-on">-</span>
        <input 
            ng-model="packer.selected.date.end"
           name="end" 
           value="<% packer.initData.dateStart %>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
Application.directive('rangepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            $(element).datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });

            $(element).on('changeDate', function(){
                /*
                $(element).find('input').each(function(){
                    $(this).trigger('input');

                }) */                
            })

        }
    };
});

Application.controller('PackingStatisticsController', ['$scope', '$http', 'initData', function($scope, $http, initData) {

    var packer = this;
    packer.initData = initData;

    packer.selected = {
        date : {
            start : "",
            end : ""
        },
        user : ""
    }

    packer.log = function()
    {
        console.log(packer.selected);
    }


}]);
```

I've read anything I thought was relevant to my issue but I haven't managed to shed the veil of confusion. The commented code is supposed to trigger the input value change event which I hoped would update the model. I fail to understand where the model I designate in the html meets my directive's data.

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html this is the plugin I'm working with.

Comment: Your HTML part is the whole directive? (because I don't see `rangepicker` anywhere)

Comment: right beside ng model, in the first div

Comment: Sorry, completely missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, i have done it!

```
Application.directive('rangepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',    // added the ngmodel requirement
        scope : {              
            ngModel: "="
        },  // also added this, which if i understood well
            // makes the 2 way data binding possible
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            $(element).datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });

            $(element).on('changeDate', function(){
                var values = $(element).find('input');
                var interval = {
                    start : values[0].value,
                    end : values[1].value
                }                

                scope.$apply(function(){
                    // and here i update the given model scope (packer.selected.data)
                    scope.ngModel = interval;
                });

            })

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: yep, pretty much what i do but you required the angular built ngModel, this is probably the preferred way but I use the require property only when i need the access to the required directive controller. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass as an attribute the model you want to modify from the controller's scope like this (look at the scope property):

```
Application.directive('rangepicker', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope : {
       model : '='
    }
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        $(element).datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });

        $(element).on('changeDate', function(){
            /*
            $(element).find('input').each(function(){
                $(this).trigger('input');

            }) */                
        })

    }
};
});
```

and in the html:

```
<div class="input-daterange datepicker full" model="myModelVar" rangepicker ng-model="packer.selected.date">
```

now the myModeVar is two way data bindable. once you change it in the directive it changes in the controller's scope.

in the controller:

```
Application.controller('PackingStatisticsController', ['$scope', '$http', 'initData', function($scope, $http, initData) {
    $scope.myModelVar = ...;
}]);
```

Comment: i saw this solution as well but it doesn't appeal that much to me. i will use it if i can't do it better, but what i hope to be able to do is have the data binding set for the ng-model and use it like i would on a normal input, or that isn't possible? or is the scope the only way to pass the data from the directive?

Comment: This is the way I'm using it, but I would be happy to hear other ways as well.